# how to split java spring to use repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, split

I have Request by status = PENDING_PAYMENT,DONE, I want to split by comma with java spring to search
data by find to repository.
how can I resolved this?

```
    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getAllOrderDetails(String status, String productName, String page, String limit) {

        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        String[] statusSplit = status.split(",");

        OrderStatus os = OrderStatus.valueOf(status.toUpperCase());
        List<Order> orders = orderRepo.findByStatus(os);

        if(orders == null){
            throw new NonexistentEntityException(ErrCode.ERR_UNKNOWN, "Order not listed");
        }

        List<OrderResult> order = new ArrayList<>();
//        order = serviceDataList.getOrderDetails(o);
        result.put("order", order);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide a repo method that takes a status array (or better a collection) as its parameter. Have a look at the [Spring Data documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods) on how to build such a method (via explicitly mentioning the query, specifications or maybe method name inference, e.g. `findByStatusIn(...)`).

Comment: also, in your controller I'd use a list query param for statuses, so you don't have to parse it yourself